QApplication in Visual Studio 2022 console not showing
I have a "console" application that depends on a lib which uses QPixmap. Therefore the application crashes if I initialize it with QCoreApplication. So instead I have to use QApplication to initialize the application. I don't even know if this causes my problem. In the Visual Studio 2022 Linker Settings I set the target system to "console" (/subsystem:console)
The application starts and everything, but I wanted the console window to show up, so that I can display qInfo() information for the admin in the console. But for any unkown reason the console is'nt showing up. I only get the "Debugger-Console" inside Visual Studio but not the "execution" console.
Does anyone of you know what settings to change to get the console visible?
Using: VS2022 with Qt 6.4.2 x64

The lib (smh) uses QPixmap, for some reason the SmartServ-app will cause a runtime crash when initialized with QCoreApplication, but works fine when initializing with QApplication, just in case this might be reason for the strange behaviour.

If it's for QPixmap only, you can also use QGuiApplication, as you don't probably need the whole desktop related aspects of QApplication.

I found the solution. I was looking up the wrong project configuration.
Setting to subsystem:console works just fine.

This makes your post invalid, because it was not reproducible or caused by a typo, and such posts are considered off topic on Stack Overflow. I'd suggest you to delete the question on your own (it will eventually be deleted anyway sooner or later).
